# ProgrammingError: while insert data in SQL using python using execute

Tags: python, sql

Here is my code:

```
  import mysql.connector
  import datetime
  import dateutil.parser
  import soundfile as sf

  mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="py",
  password="12345678",
  database="mydatabase"
   )
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  sql = "INSERT INTO customers (adress) VALUES (%s)"
  val = ("Highway 21") 
  mycursor.execute(sql, val)

  mydb.commit()

  print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

> ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
val = ("Highway 21")
sql = "INSERT INTO customers (adress) VALUES ('{}') ".format(val)
print(sql)
```

use this you will not get error

Comment: I have edited answer this will not give error now

Comment: working thanks!!! if i want to add list then what to do?

Comment: which list. Please elaborate

Comment: i want to add string list in sql table.

Comment: sql = f'INSERT INTO customers VALUES ("{var1}", '{var2}');'          use this

Comment: if my answer resolved your problem please accept it and vote it up

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal why did you leave the room conversation?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to **MySQL INSERT** statement syntax error. You can rewrite the query as follows:

```
val = "Highway 21"
sql = f'INSERT INTO customers (adress) VALUES ("{val}");'
print(sql)
# INSERT INTO customers (adress) VALUES ("Highway 21");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `,` after the "Highway 21" value since `val` needs to be a tuple because `mycursor.execute()` expects a list of values:

```
val = ("Highway 21",)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also go through this code

sql = "INSERT INTO customers (adress) VALUES ('%s')"

val = ("Highway 21")

mycursor.execute(sql%(val))